# How to eliminate following code repetition in python init function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to programming. I have created following function in a class. I noticed that I am repeating my code. I am looking for best solution to eliminate this repetition.

I have following function in my class:

```py
def init(self):
    if not os.path.exists(self.src_flag):
        if os.path.exists(self.src):
            removeFolder(self.src)
        print 'File {0} does not exist'.format(self.src_flag)
        open(self.src_flag, 'a').close()

    if not os.path.exists(self.dst_flag):
        if os.path.exists(self.dst):
            removeFolder(self.dst)
        print 'File {0} does not exist'.format(self.dst_flag)
        open(self.dst_flag, 'a').close()
```

and then I call this function by

```py
Folder.init()
```

Not sure if this will be the best approach but I was thinking to change the function to following:

```py
def init(self, flag, path):
    if not os.path.exists(flag):
        if os.path.exists(path):
            removeFolder(path)
        print 'File {0} does not exist'.format(flag)
        open(flag, 'a').close()
```

but then I have to run function twice to execute it for src and dst e.g.

```py
Folder.init('C:\src\flag.txt', 'C:\src')
Folder.init('C:\dst\flag.txt', 'C:\dst')
```

Can someone tell me if my solution is ok or maybe there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you perform the exact same block of code you should obviously use a loop. The only question is how to get the arguments, you can do that in a few ways and choose what fits best for you:

1. Just pass 2 lists: one for the paths and one for the corresponding flags. Now you can iterate over them using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip):

   ```
   def init(self, flags, paths):
       for flag, path in zip(flags, paths):
           # your block with flag and path
   ```

   You would call it like:

   `Folder.init(['C:\src\flag.txt', 'C:\dst\flag.txt'], ['C:\src', 'C:\dst'])`
2. Alternatively, pass a list of already paired `flag`s and `path`s:

   ```
   def init(self, pairs):
       for flag, path in pairs:
           # your block with flag and path
   ```

   You would call it like:

   `Folder.init([('C:\src\flag.txt', 'C:\src'), ('C:\dst\flag.txt', 'C:\dst')])`
3. Just pass all arguments together, assuming they are ordered in pairs. Then, iterate on pairs:

   ```
   def init(self, *args):
       for i in range(0, len(args)-1, 2):
           flag = args[i]
           path = args[i+1]
           # your block with flag and path
   ```

   Or, using `zip` again:

   ```
   for flag, path in zip(args[::2], args[1::2]):
       # your block with flag and path
   ```

   You would call it like: `Folder.init('C:\src\flag.txt', 'C:\src', 'C:\dst\flag.txt', 'C:\dst')`
4. Lastly, you didn't mention that in the question, but assuming `path` is the directory of the file `flag`, you can use the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html?highlight=os#module-os.path) module and just pass the flags and get `path` using the [`dirname`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.path.html?highlight=os#os.path.dirname) function:

   ```
   def init(self, *flags):
       for flag in flags:
           path = os.path.dirname(flag)
           # your block with flag and path
   ```

   You would call it like: `Folder.init('C:\src\flag.txt', 'C:\dst\flag.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array as parameter and loop over this [src,dst] array in your function. So, you could build the paths in your method and just exchange the src / dst part in the path.

This only makes sense if both src and dest are initialized always together. You could get rid of 2 similar method calls or 4 parameters, in case you would use füll paths in one single method calls

If this is not the case, I like your solution and the two calls.